# What does $\mathcal{F}_x(S)=\{A \subset S: x \notin A\}$ mean?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Pretty much the title really. What is the set $\mathcal{F}_x=\{A \subset S: x \notin A\}$. This is in the context of rings with the power set ring. I'm trying to prove this is an ideal of the power set (under the necessary operations), which I understand, but I don't have a clue what this set means. Is $\mathcal{F}_x(S)$ a field?

Edit: I missed an S in the title - sorry!

Comment: It is the collection of all subsets of $S$ which do not contain $x$.

Comment: That is, it's the power set of $S\setminus\{x\}$

Comment: There are no functions here, only subsets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe an example can help. Say we have $S = \{a, b, c, d\}$. Then we get that $\mathcal F_a$ is the set of all subsets of $S$ that do not contain $a$. Which is to say $$\mathcal F_a = \{\{b, c, d\}, \{b, c\}, \{b, d\}, \{b\}, \{c, d\}, \{c\}, \{d\}, \varnothing\}$$
If your power set ring is the standard power set ring, where addition is symmetric difference and multiplication is given by intersection, then this is clearly an ideal, as it is an additive subgroup, and intersecting with a set that doesn't contain $a$ again results in a set which doesn't contain $a$.

Comment: Thank you! I've been staring at this all day without any luck. It seems so simple now.

Answer (score 0):

The power set of a ground set $S$ can be turned into a ring by considering the symmetric difference operation for addition and the intersection operation operation for product.

In the text we are defining a subset of the power set for each element $x$. $F_x$ is the set whose elements are the subsets of $S$ that do not contain $x$.

Comment: Thank you so much - it seems so simple when it's put in words!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $$S=\{w,x,y,z\}.$$

Then
\begin{align}
\mathcal F_x & = \{ A\subset S : x\notin A\} \\[8pt]
& = \big\{ \varnothing, \{w\}, \{y\},\{z\},\{w,y\},\{w,z\},\{y,z\}, \{w,y,z\}\},
\end{align}
i.e. it is the set of all subsets of $S$ that do not have $x$ as a member.

Comment: Thank you so much - it seems so simple now!

Comment: @Heschers_Joyride99 : Notice that you can "accept" an answer.